# Asynch client connection in Netty server handler

Tags: netty

I need to open a TCP/IP client connection with my Netty Server business handler.

So

- Receive request on server socket, keep socket open
- Go through the pipleine and reach business handler...
- In business handler open asynch client connection, send request to 3rd party
- When response received from 3rd party reply back to originating client.

So in the "business" handler is there a way to fire asynch call to 3rd party and then when the 3rd party replies back some how attach back to that channel and reply back to the origin?

Or just simply, in the business handler open to 3rd party, send, receive, reply back close channel.

It's bassicaly a 1 to 1 type of thing 1 request made, 1 request/response from 3rd party, respond back with result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for something which is kind of similar to what we do in the netty examples. It's not 100% the same but kind of. Checkout the Proxy example source code:

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3.2/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy

Comment: Yes "proxy" is what I was looking for. So I receive TCP/IP with a message in it do small transform and then forward that message asynch to the 3rd party provider, get back response from 3rd party and all the way back to the requester.

Comment: Actually what I want is to receive TCP/IP and then proxy to HTTP. So I guess i can use the Hexdup sample and combine it with the HTTP Client sample?

Comment: @user432024 Have a look on http://hotpotato.biasedbit.com/, its a simple client library built for this purpose (http client library for servers) which is also uses Netty.

Comment: @JestanNirojan Thanks I'll look into it. But my biggest concern was the way to map the client events back to the requester in an asynch fashion. Which it seems the Hexdump sample is showing... Unless you telling me there a full proxy example with a sample Netty server on there.. :) But doesn't also Netty HTTP Client do this also?

Comment: @user432024 did you ever figure this out. looking for a good example of connecting client within server handler as well.